# Not show sensitive-data during a loop in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I've a list of data in my playbook. When we loop through this list Ansible show in the console the data inside. Any idea how can I hide this data from the console?

Comment: [no_log](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-keep-secret-data-in-my-playbook) ?

Comment: Yep. It is. Found in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from comments:

You can use [no_log](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-keep-secret-data-in-my-playbook) option.